# Faster / More efficient way of binding all?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is what I currently have, if/when I make a new model, I have to go and add a new line in this....
It's now starting to get longer than I'd like and is starting to bug me.

I'm using there's a shorter way, however, I cannot seem to find it.
I've tried implementing `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)`, however, I haven't been able to get it working myself.

Any help?

```py
import pathlib

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref, relationship, sessionmaker
from .models import *

path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{path}/data.db')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # order is important
    Guild.__table__.create(bind=engine)
    GuildConfig.__table__.create(bind=engine)

    User.__table__.create(bind=engine)
    Role.__table__.create(bind=engine)
    Command.__table__.create(bind=engine)

    Message.__table__.create(bind=engine)
    Trigger.__table__.create(bind=engine)

    GuildCommand.__table__.create(bind=engine)
    GuildCommandRole.__table__.create(bind=engine)

    UserMute.__table__.create(bind=engine)
    UserKick.__table__.create(bind=engine)
    UserBan.__table__.create(bind=engine)

    Reaction.__table__.create(bind=engine)
    ReactionRole.__table__.create(bind=engine)
```

Comment: What went wrong with `create_all()`? Seems like an XY situation.

Comment: XY situation? could you expand on that.... I'm completely new to any programming lingo...

Also, I'll re-create the issue that I was having and add the traceback in the next comment.

Comment: I ..... must have been doing something wrong(?)
Seems like I've tried it again (with the new SQLAlchemy update) and it all seems to work? That's.... strange

Comment: XY is used to describe a situation where one thinks that Y is a solution to X, and so asks about Y, while it might be more beneficial to ask about X directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved, just needed to check all the relationships and make sure everything was working as intended.

Also did update to the latest version of SQLAlchemy (1.3.20) and issue seems to be resolved.